# Matplotlib: imshow(imread()) gives strange results - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

[The original picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEbpi.png)

While I'm using `imgplot = plt.imshow(plt.imread('a.png'))` and `display(Image('a.png'))` to show pictures, I have two total different pictures.

[Results here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rrRv.png)

After I checked `plt.imread('a.png')` it shows strange array. What is wrong during the process?